# Unshort amazon EU link using Python

Tags: python

i'm trying to unshort amazon link using python, from pattern: "https:// amzn.eu/XXXX".

It seems the url is not recognized!

If the url is in the format "https:// amzn.to/XXXXX" it works!

Only with amzn.EU problem appears.

This is my code. Any suggest?

```
import os, pathlib, re, requests, time, warnings
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

def formaturl(url):
    if not re.match('(?:http|ftp|https)://', url):
        return 'http://{}'.format(url)
    return url

def unshort_link(url):
    url = formaturl(url)
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore',InsecureRequestWarning)
    session = requests.Session()
    resp = session.head(url, allow_redirects=True, verify=False)
    unshort_url = resp.url
    return unshort_url

not_working_link = 'https://amzn.eu/d/fb1IYWl'
#working_link = 'https://amzn.to/3A0milQ'

unshorted_url = unshort_link(not_working_link)
    
print(unshorted_url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HEAD` request doesn't work on this link, it returns a 404.

However, with a `GET` it'll work as expected:

```py
resp = requests.get('https://amzn.eu/d/fb1IYWl')
resp.url
# 'https://www.amazon.it/dp/B00HVFQF3I/ref=cm_sw_r_apa_i_9GRWP18TK8S32ZPVJVM7_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1'
```